# How to call Simple Systems Manager 'send_command' from within AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I've got an AWS Simple Systems Manager document set up, that I'm trying to trigger from AWS Lambda using Python 2.7.

My call looks like this:

```
ssmCommand = ssm.send_command(
    Targets = [
        {'Key': 'tag:Backup', 
                'Values': [
                    'db']
                 }
              ],
    DocumentName = 'set-backup-mode-begin',
    TimeoutSeconds = 240,
    Comment = 'Set Backup Mode',
    Parameters = {},)
```

But, nothing happens.  I think the problem is here:

```
Targets = [
    {'Key': 'tag:Backup', 
            'Values': [
                'db']
             }
          ]
```

Currently, there is exactly one instance with tag "Backup" and value of "db".  (If I can get this to work, there will be many more, but for now, just one.)

I think (maybe?), I'm doing something wrong, and the `Targets` is getting defined as null, so nothing happens?  It appears to be syntactically correct.  (It compiles and runs, but nothing happens.)

I'm brand new to Python and AWS Lambda.  Can someone offer a suggestion?

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: I did....it's been a while, let me go back and remember what I did, and I'll post it here.

Comment: In fact it is working. I thought that the instances Id were returned in the result but no.